# Rails, trying to run a method from one controller to another gives Unknown Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

Ok,so basically I upload an image, and I just want to reload my partial when an image is uploaded.

Every Language has many images. (Weird structure of the app, yeah.)

I want to redirect from a method from the images_controller to a method of the languages_controller.

On my **images_controller:**

```
def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    if !params[:image][:image].nil?
        if @image.save(image_params)
            @language = Language.find(params[:image][:language_id])
            @language.increment(:last_position)
            @language.save

            redirect_to load_language_partial_path(@language),:remote => true

        end
    else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {render :action => 'required_fields'}
        end
    end         
end
```

And the method on my **languages_controller**:

```
def load_partial
    @language = Language.find(params[:id])
    @image = Image.new
    @images = @language.images.order(priority: :asc)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

The thing is when I run the load partial from a link in my view, it runs perfectly, but with this it gives me

> ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
>     app/controllers/languages_controller.rb:10:in `load_partial'

I tried removing :remote = > true, but the same thing.

Is what I am trying to do not a good practice? Should I try some other way?

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**
In my language partial I got a form in which I call the **create** function for @image

```
<%=form_for @image , url: images_create_path, remote: true, multipart: true, authenticity_token: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal", :style=> "" } do |f|%>
    <h3 class="" style="float:left;margin-top:5px;"> Upload Image: </h3> 
    <div style="">
    <span>
    <%= f.file_field :image, :class => 'btn btn-default', 'data-show-upload' => false, :accept => 'image/*', :style=> 'margin-left:10px; float:left' %>

    <%= f.number_field :language_id, :value=> @language.id, :style=> 'display:none' %>
    <%= f.number_field :priority, :value=> @language.last_position, :style=> 'display:none' %>
    </span>
    <span>
    <%= submit_tag "Upload",:class => 'btn btn-primary', :style=> "margin-left:10px;height:44px" , data: { disable_with: "Uploading..." } %>
    </span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And my **load_partial.js.erb**

```
$('.page-content').html('<%= j(render partial: "/languages/languagePartial") %>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
redirect_to load_language_partial_path(@language),:remote => true
```

Try :

```
protocol = 'https://' or 'http://'
redirect_to protocol: protocol, controller: "languages", action: "load_partial", format: "js", languages: @language
```

You can skip protocol part if you want. I just gave it as I used it for my purpose. So you can use only:

```
redirect_to controller: "languages", action: "load_partial", format: "js", languages: @language
```

languages at the end is the parameter you want to pass, you can pass multiple parameters also separated by comma(,).

Comment: This actually works, but it renders the partial as text on my browser. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Do you have load_partial.js.erb created?

Comment: Yes of course. I also tried adding remote:true, to the redirect but the same result.

Comment: If you have js.erb file then try removing respond_to block from load_partial action.

Comment: Same result. Maybe I should somehow tell it I want to use "get" for routing?

Comment: The problem is on your client-side. When it receives the Ajax response, it isn't executing it as javascript. It is executing it as text. So Can you provide how you called images_controller:create action and please provide load_partial.js.erb also.

Comment: Updated, please take a look.

Comment: Try :  $('.page-content').appned('<%= j(render partial: "/languages/languagePartial") %>')..............................Notice that I have replaced .html with .append.

Comment: I get the following
 `Missing template languages/load_partial, application/load_partial with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/tasos/Projects/savvas/app/views" `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123941/discussion-between-tushar-h-and-dyserone).

Comment: sorry it was spelling mistake with append....... try : $('.page-content').empty().append('<%= j(render partial: "/languages/languagePartial") ;

Comment: I noticed the spelling mistake but I didn't think of .empty()

Comment: I still get
`Missing template languages/load_partial, application/load_partial with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/tasos/Projects/savvas/app/views"`, any hints?

Comment: Maybe I do need the respond_to block?

Comment: But looking at error, it seems that its searching for load_partial.html.erb file.  Is this happening just because of changing html by append ?

Comment: If I add an load_partial.html.erb file, and without using the respond_to block, it renders it.

Comment: How do I make it look for a js file?

Comment: Can you please check whats the request type (HTML/JS) in log file for both  create and load_partial actions when they gets called?. Because Ideally server should look for js files not html files.

Comment: After a whole day and trying many different things, I finally solved it. I will upload the answer tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for your awesome help.